# draw graph and edges based on some metrics e.g degree of centrality

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, social-networking

I want to show a graph for the topmost degree of centrality. My question seems similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51461382/how-to-draw-graph-based-on-centrality); however, the solution provided there doesn't work. I have also seen the answers to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67190637/change-color-size-of-graph-in-networkx-based-on-degree-centrality-measure) but I don't want to show all the nodes. Below a process, I have tried without success.

```py
import networkx as nx

df = pd.read_csv("filepath")
graph = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(data, source="source", target="target")
eigen_centrality = nx.eigenvector_centrality(graph)
node_list = sorted(eigen_centrality, key=eigen_centrality.get, reverse=True)[:20]
nx.draw_networkx(graph, nodelist=node_list, pos=nx.spring_layout(graph))
```